# Convertion HTML to Razor

Tags: razor

We are changing from WebForm to MVC 4 using Razor

How can I translate this HTML line using Razor ?

```
<a class="btn btn-black-sisloc btn-input" href="#">
    <i class="glyphicons plus icon-white-qrcode"></i>
        CREATE
</a>
```

We have some doubts in delivery the class to a `ActionLink` and put a `<i>` tag inside

Comment: Razor is a server-side syntax.  You can use normal HTML, like this, in your views.  There's no need for *all* markup to be produced by server-side functionality.

Comment: The advantage will be that in the ActionLink I could refer to a ActionView in my Controller, but with just HTML (without Razor), I make this with JQuery

Comment: The code shown has no reference to any server-side resources.  Perhaps you can elaborate on what you're actually trying to accomplish?  Because your question in its current form doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: So, a doubt, if a View has .cshtml format, how can I call this View in a `html link <a>` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "call a view"?  A link makes a GET request to a server-side resource.  In ASP.NET MVC, requests are received by controller action methods.  So you can "call an action" in that sense.  The action may or may not result in returning a view.  So if you link to an action, you can receive back a view.  If you're just asking how to create a link in Razor, `@Html.ActionLink` does that.  If you need more customization, you can build your own markup an use `@Url.Action` to provide just the URL component of that markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is valid, and it is correct while you would transfer your website from Web Forms to MVC

```
<a class="btn btn-black-sisloc btn-input" href="#">
    <i class="glyphicons plus icon-white-qrcode"></i>
        CREATE
</a>
```

The above code would execute perfectly.

Similarly, the element, `<i>` is for changing the element's `font-style` property to `italic`. It has no other functionality in your web page.

Razor is a server-side language, you should worry about change the Server-side code needed to run the website.

Comment: The `<i>` tag is used to display a glyphicon in earlier versions of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Razor is a superset of HTML.  That is valid HTML so it is valid Razor already.

Comment: Razor is a templating syntax. It is not a superset of HTML. There is no Razor in the snippet posted by the OP.